# converting a hours from a time stamp into a hash listing the hour and frequency in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, time

Ok, so I'm pretty new at this, I hope I explain this correctly. I'm using Ruby, and I have a program which takes a CSV file and performs some various functions on it. What I'm concerned with here is the TIME portion. I took a column of data which was a string, and used this method to convert it to DateTime and give me just the hour part:

```
def hour_reg(regdate)
  regdate.to_s
  time_stamp = DateTime.strptime("#{regdate}", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").hour
  time_stamp
end
```

that part works fine. so now I'm trying to take that HOUR that I just got, and convert that into a HASH which displays the Hour of the day (1 through 24), and how many times each hour comes up. For example, if the hour 1 came up (for 1AM) 3 separate times, it would display: {1 => 3} in the hash. here's what the code looks like that iterates through the column of TIMES, indicated by ":regdate"

```
contents.each do |row|
  id = row[0]
  name = row[:first_name]
  zipcode = clean_zipcode(row[:zipcode])
  **reg_time = hour_reg(row[:regdate])**
end
```

Basically I want the frequency of each hour. can anyone help with this? I'm having a great deal of trouble

Comment: Have you tried something like `my_hour_freq[key] += 1`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Hash with 1-24 keys, initialized to 0.

```
h = { 1 => 0, 2 => 0, ...}
```

Then do this to increment the hash. I'm assuming the hour_reg method returns an integer.

```
h[hour_reg(row[:regdate])] += 1
```

Also you can simplify your hour_reg method to:

```
def hour_reg(regdate)
  DateTime.strptime("#{regdate}", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").hour
end
```

Updating my answer to reflect the discussion in comments:

```
#get contents from CSV file
contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol 

# create Hash h with 1-24 keys initialized to 0
h = {}
(1..24).each {|x| h[x] = 0}

contents.each do |row| 
  reg_time = hour_reg(row[:regdate]).to_i 
  h[reg_time] += 1 
end
```

The hour frequency is stored in the "h" hash.
You can simplify the above "contents" block to a single line if you want:

```
contents.each do {|row| h[hour_reg(row[:regdate]).to_i] += 1}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this was extremely helpful, but I have one more question if you could enlighten me a bit more. I've added this to my code:

    hour = []

    hour << reg_time

    freq = hour.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |k,v| k[v] += 1; h }

with this, I can display the data in Hash form, with the hour being the key, and then it's frequency. The problem I'm having is that I want to add 1 to the value, indicating multiple instances of that key. for example:

Instead of:
a => 1
a => 1

I'd like to display
a => 2

How would I go about doing that now that I actually have it in Hash form?

Comment: Have a few questions:  1. Did the above code not give you the hash of hour frequency? It works for my test case.  2. In your above comment, what is reg_time?  3. In the inject block what is h?

Comment: Here's what the relevant code looks like:

def hour_reg(regdate)
  DateTime.strptime("#{regdate}", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").hour
end


contents = CSV.open 'event_attendees.csv', headers: true, header_converters: :symbol


contents.each do |row|
  id = row[0]
  reg_time = hour_reg(row[:regdate])

  reg_time.to_i

  hour = []

  hour << reg_time
  
  freq = hour.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }

 puts freq
end

***I'm trying to take each hour listed (1-24 for hours in a day), and create a Hash showing each Hour in the day, and how many times that specific hour came up.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I strongly suggest you review your Ruby basics. I've updated the answer above with the whole code, basically giving you the answer. In your code in the above comment, the id variable is not being used, the reg_time.to_i returns an integer but is not saved in any variable so is wasted code, don't see the use of assigning reg_time to hour array and I don't see the use of having h at the end of the inject block because the block will work without the last h. Hence my recommendation that you review the basics of Ruby. Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm trying to learn all of this by myself with no programming background so it's very difficult for me. I know I have a long way to go in understanding concepts and things. Thanks for taking the time to help out a newbie, I really appreciate it. I'll keep at it!